# How to get rid of unwanted Linux X start-up glitch

Tags: linux, boot, xorg

We have a system where we have a "splash" screen (managed via [Plymouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_%28software%29)) and an application which is started when X is starting.

However between the two (that is, after the screen of Plymouth goes away and before we can see the screen of the application) there is a glitch (a black screen shown for half a second or so), easily recognizable, because the logo of Plymouth has a white background with some graphics, and the application has a white background with text on it.

How do I get rid of this black screen? Any tips, hints, etc.?

The computer is a NexCom [VTC 6200-NI-HE](http://www.nexcom.com/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc/in-vehicle-pc/transportation-computer-vtc-6200-ni) and the OS installed is a home brewn OS ***based on*** [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal).

Comment: I don't think you can. It sounds like the normal flicker you get when X starts. Inn any case, we can;t help at all unless you tell us your graphics card, which driver you use, which X version you use, how you launch X etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the Plymouth screen is a different resolution than your final desktop resolution. The flicker is due to the screen switching resolutions.

Try to match the Plymouth screen resolution to the final desktop resolution. You could do it the other way around, but that would probably make your final desktop low-resolution.